# Itronix Windows XP Ubuntu installation fails

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have attempted to install Ubuntu on my Itronix computer to no avail. Every attempt ends in an incomplete set of installation files which will not run. Is there a unique Windows XP installation on this machine? If so has anyone encountered similar problems? I have attempted to install Ubuntu 12, 14, and the most recent builds.

System specifics:

- Microsoft XP Professional version 2002, Service Pack 3
- Itronix GoBook III (IX260+)
- Intel Pentium M Processor 1.80 GHz
- 1.00 GB RAM
- Memory 1042 MB
- AMI BIOS P16D1.190

Comment: Can you give us more information? As in how much ram, what processor etc. You may simply not have enough power to run ubuntu, in that case try lubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)